# Cant loop on selector jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop over $("#"+i) 
but it doesn't work. it keeps giving a error.
What is the correct way to loop over $() selector with jquery

error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of
>   undefined(anonymous function) @ VM3311:29(anonymous function) @
>   total-minS.js?v=15:1
>   (anonymous function)  @   VM3311:29 (anonymous
>   function) @   total-minS.js?v=15:1

code:

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         test
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @author       You
// @match        https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
// @grant        none
// @include http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


    var list2 = [];
setTimeout(function () { test(); }, 4100);

function test() {
$( document ).ready(function() {

    for(var j = 0; j < 15; j++){
        alert(j.toString());
        var list1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         var x = $("#"+j).find('ul').find('li').find('span');
         var content = x[i].innerText || x[i].textContent; 
        list1[i] = content;
    }
    list2 += list1;
    }
    document.write(list2);
});
}
```

Comment: Post your code and error you have got, that will be helpful.

Comment: Don't loop it, IDs must be unique! you'll always get one element and its useless to try loop for it. try class instead and loop through it!

Comment: Could you show your html and more code?

Comment: Which error? Add the whole code to your question.

Comment: Im trying to create a crawler, im using client side javascript. I'm running javascript on someone else his website by tampermonkey. I'm crawling my grades and those elements have id= 1 id=2 etc

Comment: Only numeric ids is not valid, but don't think jQuery will enforce that. Could you paste error description?

Comment: i see, but for some reason it should format it to $("#1") and $("#2") right?

Comment: since you are executing it in a loop it should work, print and see if the `var x` has content in it.

Comment: it is returning [Object Array] in a Alert

Comment: Solved! I was starting on id = 0 when id started on 1. My bad! im very sorry for this question i feel kinda dumb right now

Comment: No problem, you found the solution correct. ;)